# Differences between test results in GitHub actions and local run

Tags: .net, unit-testing, github, testing, github-actions

First-time poster.

I was observing that there was a difference between the local run of the Dotnet functional tests and the one in GitHub actions. All tests work flawlessly in the local env, but in the GitHub actions, it throws the following error:

```
Failed ShouldRespondWithContent_OnInvalidCitiesRequest [72 ms]
  Error Message:
   Expected actual.Detail to be 
"Cities are invalid" with a length of 18, but 
"Cities are invali" has a length of 17, differs near "i" (index 16).
```

It is weird because the last string

> Cities are invali

is not defined anywhere in the files, but I can`t get my head around why the string is getting shortened automatically.

Is this an error from GitHub pipelines envs or am I missing something else here?

GitHub actions file:

```
name: CI build

## action designed to test in all branches but master

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**" ## all branches
      - "!master" ## except master
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 5.0.x
      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --no-restore
      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

Test code (the dotnet version we are using in both runs is 5.0.404):

```
public async Task ShouldRespondWithContent_OnInvalidCitiesRequest()
        {
            var valuesByKey = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                ["cities"] = new() { "" }
            };
            _requestUriBuilder.AddQueryParameter(valuesByKey);

            var response = await Client.GetAsync(_requestUriBuilder.ToString());

            var problemDetailsExpected = new ValidationProblemDetails
            {
                Title = "https://httpstatuses.com/400",
                Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                Detail = "Cities are invalid",
                Instance = "/api/accommodations",
                Errors =
                {
                    ["Cities[0]"] = new []{ "Cities are invalid" }
                }
            };
            var problemDetails = await response.DeserializeAsync<ProblemDetails>();
            Asserter.Assert(problemDetailsExpected, problemDetails);
        }
```

Validation error definition (where the string that is getting shortened is defined):

```
namespace Deribe.Domain.ConstantValues
{
    public static class ValidationErrorMessages
    {
        public const string InvalidId = "Id is invalid";
        public const string InvalidCities = "Cities are invalid";
    }
}
```

Test base file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Deribe.FunctionalTest.Fake;
using Deribe.Tests.Common.TestUtilities.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Deribe.FunctionalTest.TestBases
{
    public class NotAuthenticatedTestBase : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
    {
        protected HttpClient Client;
...
public NotAuthenticatedTestBase()
        {
            Client = CreateClient();
        }
```

Comment: You're leaving out a critical piece of information: How that `Client` instance is configured. Is this a unit test or an integration test? I don't see anything being mocked.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann , I have edited the question to add the test base file. These are functional tests

Comment: Please include **all the relevant code**. What does `CreateClient` do? The most likely culprit is that something is configured differently on your local machine versus when you run the test as part of CI, but that's only a hypothesis. Your best bet is to treat this as a bug in the test and troubleshoot the problem through the usual means. i.e. putting more verbose logging in place, investigating the request being sent versus the payload received back, and so forth. It's unlikely that the broader Stack Overflow community will be able to provide much help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.